# Python child class initialiser argument

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization

I have a parent class whose initialiser has three argument, now I want to have a child class whose initialiser only has two argument, but it's telling me it has to be given three arguments when I try to create the child object.

```
class Parent(Exception):
    def _init_(self, a, b):
    ...
    super(Parent, self)._init_(a, b)

class Child(Parent):
    def _init_(self, b):
        super(Child, self)._init_(123, b)

# somewhere in the code I have:
raise Child("BAD_INPUT")
```

What I'm trying to do is instantiate a Child object with only one argument then in the initialiser of that Child object call Parent's initialiser and pass in two argument, one is hard-coded (123) .

Error I got:
`TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: `_init_ -> __init__`?

Comment: When I run this code and fix the indent on `super(Parent, self)._init_(a, b)` I get no exception, except for the one you raise

Comment: OMG!!! I wasted hours on this, __ is really the problem!! Python should give me a better error message.. T T

Comment: Maybe you remove your question in that case? The title is very misleading. "Python child class initialiser argument" I think there is no use to save code with typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use:

```
class Parent(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Child(Parent):
    a = 123
    def __init__(self, b):
        super().__init__(self.a, b)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `__super__`. And the problem is with the `_init_` missing extra underscores which your answer does not solve